# NodeJs redirect to different domain

Tags: node.js, nginx

1. how to redirect with two different domain with NodeJs
2. i have one sub-domain with https://service.test.in:1234 & also want to redirect same code to https://service.test.ae:1235 with SSL
3. so how can i redirect to both sub-domain with same code also with SSL?
4. here is the code of server.js

   ```
   const sslOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync("./privateKey.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("./reportservice_test_in.crt"),
        ca: [
             fs.readFileSync('./COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt'),
             fs.readFileSync('./COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt')
        ]
   };

   app.get(virtualDirPath + '/test', function (req, res) {
     return res.json({
         "status": "server is running..."
     })
   })

   var server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app);
   var port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
   server.listen(port, function () {
     console.log("started server")
   });
   ```

Comment: It seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what do you want to achieve at the end? Maybe this redirect idea is not possible, or probably you'll need to call a different piece of code within your application or you wanted to have a [load balencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) for your applications.

Please try to explain what you wanted to achieve at the end, or maybe some details about your problem (What do you have for now and what did you expect and why) will be so helpful

Comment: @Fcmam5 currently my https://service.test.in:1234 server is working fine, but i also have **https://service.test.ae:1235** that server so whenever i call test.ae i want to redirect it to test.in, i think this is possible with **nginx**, but i don't know how it works

Comment: Have you tried sending a ``Location`` HTTP header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. install nginx in your server using **sudo apt install nginx** command
2. go to **cd /etc/nginx/sites-available**
3. open **nano default** file edit as per your requirement
4. if you want to redirect another domain to same then create new file at **/etc/nginx/sites-available** and change as per your requirement
5. here is the sample file code

   ```
       server {
           listen 443 ssl;

           server_name "~^(\w{1,61}+)\.test2.india\.in$" test2.india.in;

           client_header_timeout 120s;

           client_max_body_size 50m;
           uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
           uwsgi_send_timeout 300;
           uwsgi_buffer_size 8k;
           client_body_buffer_size 32K;
           large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

           gzip on;
           gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
           gzip_vary on;
           gzip_proxied any;
           gzip_comp_level 6;
           gzip_buffers 16 8k;
           gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

           location / {
                   proxy_pass http://test1.india.in;
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           }

       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/certificate_file.crt; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/privateKey.key; # managed by Certbot
   }
   server {
       if ($host = test2.india.in) {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       } # managed by Certbot


           listen 80;
           server_name "~^(\w{1,61}+)\.test2.india\.in$" test2.india.in;
       return 404; # managed by Certbot


   }
   ```
6. after create multiple file then run below command
7. **ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**
8. **ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default_ae.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**

> [for more information visite this link](https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/how-configure-nginx-to-serve-multiple-websites-single-vps#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20a,to%20host%20all%20your%20domains.)